# How to set a key combination as a browser toolbar shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, browser, toolbar

For example, something like:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

...or whatever else. I'd like to have an icon in my browser's toolbar that when clicked executes such a key combination.

Is this directly possible, or would it require creating a plugin? If it *would* require creating a plugin, how might that be done?

---

*p.s. — I'm using Firefox, but it would be awesome if there was a browser-independent solution.*

EDIT:  @crazypotato has a good solution for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> as being a link to `chrome://browser/content/sanitize.xul` in Firefox, but I'm thinking of something that might function more like a [keyboard macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_%28computer_science%29#Keyboard_and_mouse_macros).

Comment: You want create shortcut on bookmark toolbar for hotkey CTRL+SHIFT+DEL what will execute  "clear browser history" while CTRL+SHIFT+DEL already execute "clear browser history"? Why you cant make bookmark on url "clear browser history" for firefox (chrome://browser/content/sanitize.xul)
for chrome (chrome://settings/clearBrowserData). This question hurt me alot:( Why you can't ask for way to execute "clear browser history" in bookmark toolbar.

Comment: @crazypotato OK chrome://browser/content/sanitize.xul works, wasn't aware of that, thanks! My question is misleading, because I'm more curious if a link could execute any possible key combination, not just CTRL+SHIFT+DEL. Edited just now --

Comment: Instead you should find how execute function behind hotkey and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) but this very not safe and not worth using it. Unless make white list and block everything else for executable files.

First you should register [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) for example with this [app](http://goo.gl/trX9bB) (windows executable). This app from [Local Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/local-explorer-file-manag/eokekhgpaakbkfkmjjcbffibkencdfkl/details) - File Manager for Chrome, open files and folders on local directories or network shares.
Then you can run **any** file from your drive using any browser.

For next step need create script with [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) or [AHK](http://ahkscript.org/) for send keys.

After install [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) and [Editor](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/). Right click on desktop->New->Autoit Script. Right click on this created file->Edit. Now you should see ScITE window and after line "Add your code below here" add this code:

```
#NoTrayIcon
send("^+{DEL}")
```

This script send keys(ctrl+shift+delete) to active window(click on send and press F1 for help).
Then in SciTE window press Tools->Build. Now you will get executable in same directory where was Autoit script.

For execute file in browser you should run in address bar or add to bookmark this url:

```
localexplorer:[full path to executable]
```

Example:

```
localexplorer:C:\sendkeys.exe
```

For each combination of hotkeys you should create own Autoit script.

Comment: I will have to research this, thanks @crazypotato!